# Why is response time deterministic on RTOS such as preempt-rt kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, operating-system, embedded, rtos

Why is response time deterministic on RTOS such as preempt-rt kernel?
What feature in preempt-rt is different from one in vanilla kernel?

I seek for the reason and I found it has something to do with "spinlock".
However I can't understand what "spinlock" is and how it effects response time.

Comment: Linux is not an RTOS - even with preempt-rt.

Comment: This is a quite huge topic. However making response time deterministic is the problem shall be solved by any RTOS. So first sentence is kind of weird.  Also holding spin lock in  one process in kernel might prevent other process response time nondeterministic, so a sleeping spin lock might help. [Source](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/locking/locktypes.html).

Answer (score 3):

The answer to the question "Why is response time deterministic on RTOS?" has little to do with spinlocks.  Spinlocks is (at least in part) an answer to a *a different* question *"Why is the response time of the default Linux kernel non-deterministic?*

A typical RTOS scheduler uses a priority-based preemptive policy and kernel code that is itself *deterministic*.  That is to say it provides strict, bounded and *generally* short guarantees with respect to the CPU time spent in context switching, interrupt latency, and kernel calls.  It achieves this by avoiding both busy-waits (spinlocks) and disabling of interrupts (at least for unbounded periods).

The default Linux scheduler does not provide those guarantees in part due to the use of spinlocks.  The PREEMPT_RT kernel enables both priority-based pre-emptive kernel scheduling and replaces some spinlocks in the Linux kernel with mutexes to improve determinism.  The default SCHED_OTHER policy is a simple time-slice scheduler that is intrinsically non-deterministic and unsuited to real-time.  SCHED_FIFO, SCHED_RR and SCHED_DEADLINE provide scheduling policies more suited to real-time systems, but remain scheduling policies for a kernel that itself was never designed for hard real-time determinism, which constructs such as spinlocks defeat.  PREEMPT_RT addresses the main causes of non-deterministic behaviour in the kernel, but does not truly make Linux an RTOS.  In particular interrupt response remains and issue.